# C# Thread error

Tags: c#, multithreading

So im attempting to create a auto typer. And the problem is if i spam the message, And click the application to stop the spam it just freezes up. I as then told i need to use Threads. So i had a read around and this is what i came up with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace tf2trade
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public bool started = true;

        private void spam()
        {
            string test = text1.Text;
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            while (started == false)
            {
                foreach (char c in test)
                {
                    SendKeys.Send(c.ToString());
                }
                SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
            }
        }

        Thread test = new Thread(spam);

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (started == true)
            {
                started = false;
                submit.Text = "Stop";
                submit.Refresh();
                spam();
            }
            else 
            {
                started = true;
                submit.Text = "Start";
            }




        }
    }
}
```

Now this code gives me the error:

```
A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'tf2trade.Form1.spam()'
```

What did i do wrong? :(

Thanks in advance,
Alana.

Comment: The error tells you pretty much what it is: A field initializer (`Thread test = new Thread(spam);`) cannot reference the non-static method `tf2trade.Form1.spam()`. You also really don’t want to call that spam method from within the button’s click handler.

Comment: @poke But if i make it static, It creates more errors. Also what should i be doing instead of calling it from the click handler?

Comment: Don’t create the trehad from the field initializer. Create the thread, e.g. in the constructor, or in another method. And you don’t want to call the method in the click handler, since it contains `Thread.Sleep` and that will halt the UI thread causing your application to stop responding to user input.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I wouldn't waste your time troubleshooting this error. Instead, consider using one of the existing approaches to writing multi-threaded applications in .NET .  The technology you use will depend on the type of problem you are trying to solve. For short/quick tasks consider using:

- thread pool
- .net task library

If you are creating a "long" running task you could create 1 or more native threads, but I wouldn't recommend doing this until you have a better understanding of what you are doing. There are a lot of pitfalls. For example, A lot of developers think more threads equals better performance... this is not true.

**REFERENCES**

- thread pool:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx
- tasks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx
- native thread: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx